# Secure Connection Failed - ColdFusion 2018

Tags: ssl, https, coldfusion

I have ColdFusion 2018 installed on my computer. Recently I made some changes and I can't access my server files. If I enter `https://127.0.0.1:8500/cfm/welcome.cfm` in browser url this error showed on the screen:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8500. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error. I shouldn't have `https` on my local server since I do not have certificate installed. For some reason it's always putting `https` in my url address. If you know what could cause this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/8rilyj/ssl_error_rx_record_too_long/

> For me the fix was to disable TLS 1.3 for now.
>
> You can do it by doing this:
>
> Write to your address bar: about:config
>
> - Search for: security.tls.version.max
> - Change the value from 4 to 3.
> - Click ok and you should be good to go!
> - The broken sites should start working instantly!
>
> 4 stands for TLS 1.3 and 3 for TLS 1.2